# 'react/bridging/Bridging.h' file not found react native build iOS

Tags: react-native

I am trying to build my project for iOS

- react-native: `0.68.2`
- react: `17.0.2`

But I get this error on iOS: `'react/bridging/Bridging.h' file not found` in `Pods/Development Pods/React-Codegen/FBReactNativeSpec.JSI`

My minimum iOS deployment target is `12.4`

Comment: any luck with this bug ? I have a problem with `'butter/map.h' file not found` and the only bug is on reanimated and I don't have reanimted on the project already

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I encountered the exact same issue, and it turned out that the contents of the `ios/build/generated` folder were in an inconsistent state.

By removing the contents of the `ios/build` folder and the `Pods` folder, followed by running `pod install`, I managed to fix the error.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! it solves my problem but new ones appeared :(

Answer (score 3):

Your Podfile should look like this:

```
  config = use_native_modules!
  flags = get_default_flags()
  use_frameworks!
  use_react_native!(
                :path => config[:reactNativePath],

                :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
                :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
                :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
              )
post_install do |installer|
  # https://github.com/facebook/react- 
  native/blob/main/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
   react_native_post_install(
     installer,
     :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
   )
   __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
end
```

And than `rm -rf Pods` , `rm -rf Podfile.lock`, `rm -rf build`, `pod cache clean --all` and finally `pod install`

After all of them it worked for me. I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Ahmet 
just a quick all in one command for future hunters

cd ios && rm -rf Pods && rm -rf Podfile.lock && rm -rf build && pod cache clean --all && pod install